# How to split long C/C++ code line on two lines without inserting new line number?

Tags: line-breaking, minted, sourcecode

I am using the following snippet to insert C/C++ code into my LaTeX document but the problem is that the code on one line is too long and it goes over the right side of the document page. How to split this on two lines? I tried to simply move part of the line to another line but then it also introduces a new line number on the side.

```
\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
linenos
]
{cpp}
void angle_PD()
{
  anglePWM = kp_angle * (angleSetpoint - angle) + kd_angle * (angularSpeed0 - angular_speed);
}
\end{minted}
\caption{PD controller}
%\label{code:3}
\end{listing}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related. Anyway, would using `\begin{minted}[breaklines]` solve your problem?

Comment: I used \begin{minted}[breaklines] and it gives an error:

Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was

probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.285 \end{minted}